# How to include pytz with cx_Freeze when doing it in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, cx-freeze, pytz

I had to ask this again, because [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606932/cx-freeze-how-do-i-add-package-files-into-library-zip) solves the problem when there is no virtualenv involved.

Now I have more than one virtualenv that I would like to package in executables using cx_Freeze. I run my cx_Freeze setup file normally using virtualenv python interpreter, but then when I try to execute my program, pytz doesn't find the files, probably because if you see the error below, it is searching them in the original directory of virtualenv where they were located. I checked the time zone files are located correctly into the zip file.

This is the error message I get when trying to run my bundled program:

```
cserpell@e431:~/src/build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7$ ./validate 
/home/cserpell/src/build/exe.linux-x86_64-2.7/library.zip/distutils/__init__.py:14: UserWarning: The virtualenv distutils package at %s appears to be in the same location as the system distutils?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cserpell/src/virtualenvtest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cx_Freeze/initscripts/Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "scripts/validate.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/home/cserpell/src/scripts/script.py", line 15, in <module>
    from common import time_util
  File "/home/cserpell/src/common/time_util.py", line 31, in <module>
    SCL_TZ = pytz.timezone('America/Santiago')
  File "/home/cserpell/src/virtualenvtest/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/__init__.py", line 180, in timezone
    raise UnknownTimeZoneError(zone)
pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'America/Santiago'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. The only thing needed was to install setuptools in my virtualenv. For the record, it is very strange that I installed it using pip in the virtualenv, but then when I run pip list or pip freeze, it doesn't show setuptools as requirement, though it is for the cx freeze script.

Comment: I had the same problem but setuptools didn't help :/